# How to avoid multiple invoking of Background Task for every pending raw push

Tags: windows-rt, background-task, wns

How to avoid invoking background task for every pending raw push delivered to application from wns server when user returns to connected state after being temporarily disconnected in windows runtime 8.1?

I just want to invoke my background task just once for all pending raw pushes?